# php array cart problem?

Tags: php, arrays, shopping-cart

I have the following code:

```
if($_SESSION['basket']){
    $i=0;
    while($i < count($_SESSION['basket'])) {    
        if(is_array($_SESSION['basket'][$i][$product['productid']]) && $_SESSION['basket'][$i][$product['productid']]['material']==$_POST['material'] && $_SESSION['basket'][$i][$product['productid']]['size']==$_POST['size']){
            $_SESSION['basket'][$i][$product['productid']]['qty']+=$_POST['qty'];
        }else{
            echo $i."-4";
            $_SESSION['basket'][][$product['productid']] = array("qty"=>$_POST['qty'], "material"=>$_POST['material'],"size"=>$_POST['size']);
        }
        $i++;
    }   
}else{
    $_SESSION['basket'][][$product['productid']] = array("qty"=>$_POST['qty'], "material"=>$_POST['material'],"size"=>$_POST['size']);
}
```

and when I add an item to the basket the qty displayed for a product is 2 when I am only adding 1 also sometimes extra products are also sometime added can anyone help me?

Comment: I would urge you to assign huge variable name values to shorter, more descriptive variable names when you execute operations. It would make all this so much easier. For instance `$prodID = &$_SESSION['basket'][$i][$product['productid']]`. Now you can perform all your operations on `$prodID` instead.

Comment: Hi Codemonkey,
I completely agree with you, I was going to do this after figuring out the problem.
Thanks

Comment: @Dino You've posted 15 questions. You should learn how to properly format code blocks so other people don't have to keep fixing them for you. Don't use `<code>` or `<pre>` tags, ever. Select your code and click the `{ }` button from the toolbar, or manually indent each line 4 spaces. To write `code inline, like this`, wrap the text in `\`backticks\``. Please [read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Answer (score 0):

I would double check that `$_SESSION['basket'][$i][$product['productid']]['qty']` plus `$_POST['qty']` equals your desired value for starters, echo it out, make sure they're ints (if you haven't already)

And try

```
$_SESSION['basket'][$i][$product['productid']]['qty'] = $_SESSION['basket'][$i][$product['productid']]['qty'] + $_POST['qty'];
```

instead of using the `+=` operator.  It's given me problems in the past.

Or your `count($_SESSION['basket'])` may be equaling `2`, therefor running the addition twice.